# Questions about GPSIM

Tags: simulator, pic, microchip

Has someone knowledge about the GPSIM's PAL_VIDEO module,  a screenshot how is it shown after initialization or a sample code?
In Gpsim 0.31.0 timer0 doesn't works as counter with external signal at pin `RA2`. Is it a known problem or only mine? A sample code about

```
OPTION_REG = 0b10111000 ;
OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 1 ;
TMR0 = 0 ; 
delay_ms(10); //delay 10ms 
OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0 ;
```

The code works fine with PIC16f877 in gpsim 0.31.0. Using SDCC compiler 3.9.0

Comment: Did you configure `RA2* as an digital input? On default it is analog.

Comment: Yes i did. I tried and pic 16f628 it works. It doesnt work only with pic16f676 selected, it doesnt count the external signal